# Проблема после редактирования .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

Появилась необходимость избавиться на сайте от "*.html" и тп. Полез в инет искать информацию. Нашел инфу о этом злополучном файле. После его изменения, все казалось бы хорошо, помимо того факта, что перестали открываться другие страницы на сайте. Написал в нем следующее:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

После сего, уже и удалял файл, и редактировал, ничего не могу с этим поделать. Знающие, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?